# How to handle SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

OS : UBUNTU 20.04 LTS
Google chrome -Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)
conda: 4.9.1
Selenium: 3.141.0

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    driver =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/blank/Downloads/useless/chromedriver_linux64 (3)/chromedriver',options=options)`
```

### It was working a day before i dont know whats the problem .

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64)

Comment: I got the solution by help of a friend . 


!pip install webdriver_manager
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

Comment: I had to remove `options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')` in my case. Not sure why, maybe it's deprecated or something?

Answer (score 2):

This mean your chrome driver is unable to initiate/spawn a new Chrome Browser. It might happen due to many reason so i not 100% sure but this is things i usually do:

1. Re-check chrome driver, jdk and selenium version, make sure it compatibility with Chrome Browser on your computer
2. Ensure that /etc/hosts on your system contains the following entry (if using mac or linux):

**127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost**
#or
**127.0.0.1 localhost loopback**

3. Turn off antivirus (some can affect chrome driver)
4. clear all data and reboot system.

Comment: The versions are compatible with each other and updated . I am not sure what u mean by /etc/hosts . Please elaborate on the method . I have also uninstalled each application and reinstalled again , even tried to use Firefox but same error is encountered .